# Skipping char-string values while comparing to a column values of mixed type to int or float in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one column have mixed type values in it:

```
df
name   ref
 a     100
 b     103.78
 c     own
 d     108
 e     abc@yahoo.com
 f     110.45
```

So the `ref` col has mixed type. Now I have to query on it like:

```
 d = df[df['ref'] > 105]

 # got error can't comapre str() with int
 # so i did changed the dtype to float
 df['ref'] = df['ref'].astype(float)
 # cant convert str to float 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

After googling it, I can now convert the column values to float in one go:

```
 # using 
 df['ref'] = df['ref'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

But demerit is, it makes the `char` strings to `Nan`, which is causing problem in next df operation. of-course my query `d = df[df['ref'] > 105]`  is working.

But is there a way to skip checking char string while comparing the column values to int and vice versa...so that my query will work and the char string will remain as it's.

Something like:

```
d = df[df['ref']>103].skip_charstrings=True
## then i don't have to worry about char or nan or dtype as a whole.
```

Comment: @jezrael-after applying your suggestion when i queried  i got TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print df[(pd.to_numeric(df['ref'], errors='coerce').notnull()) & (df['ref']>103)]
  name     ref
1    b  103.78
3    d  108.00
5    f  110.45
```

Comment: @jezrael-same error TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int().....i am using python 3.4.3 and pandas 0.16.1  is it anything to deal with versions.

Comment: If you have old version pandas, try `print df[(df['ref'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).notnull()) & (df['ref']>103)]`

Comment: well error again   FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.  then same TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: So you try convert  to string before `df['ref'] = df['ref'].astype.(str)`

Answer (score 1):

Coerce `df.ref` to numeric values, use `gt` to get a boolean mask of those greater than zero, and display the original uncoerced values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'},
                   'ref': {0: 100, 1: 103.78, 2: 'own', 3: 108, 4: 'abc@yahoo.com', 5: 110.45}})

>>> df[pd.to_numeric(df.ref, 'coerce').gt(103)]
  name     ref
1    b  103.78
3    d     108
5    f  110.45
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a boolean series that can be used as a mask, obtaining all df rows in which ref can be converted to numeric.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.ref,'coerce').notnull()
```

This is not enough as the column dtype is still str.

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.ref,'coerce').notnull()].ref > 105
```

So you have to use astype(int) before making the comparison.

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.ref,'coerce').notnull()].ref.astype(int) > 105
```

And this will finally return the mask that you want. So this should work and will not modify your string values:

```
d = df[df[pd.to_numeric(df.ref,'coerce').notnull()].ref.astype(int) > 105]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Cool Explanation. But i ma getting IndexError for the last snippet. : as pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: Got it worked by  df.ix[(df[pd.to_numeric(df.ref,'coerce').notnull()].ref.astype(int) > 105).index], 
      i:e df.ix[df.index(criteria)] format

Comment: Happy that it has been useful. Don't know why in my case it was not necessary the index specification... Just to know, which pandas version are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas '0.20.2' version.