# Pandas dataframe: converting mixed-typed string values to float while keeping track of the true string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I've scrub a table from a web page. 
Some columns hold dollar amounts or percentage (as strings), but some entries have some notes, i.e '(n)'.
Before I can transform the str(numbers) to float, I need to inspect the notes to find out if they should get 0 or NA.

What I need is to output the row and note for each entry with a note, i.e. 
    (4, '(4)'), (13, '(4)');  # or vectors

Using python: 3.5.4; pandas: 0.22.0

I've reproduced a smaller dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[ '$104.64', '$73.04', '(4)', '$82.95', '$92.45', '$95.09', 
                    '$79.20', '$63.66', '$90.27', '$98.80', '$33.82', '(8)', '$56.74', '$49.22', 
                    '$75.74'], 
               'B':['%28.90', '%73.36', '(3)', '%104.64', '%73.04', '%82.95',  
                    '%79.20', '(9)', '%63.66', '%90.27', '%98.80', '%33.82', '%56.74', '%49.22', 
                    '%75.74']})
df

        A   B
0   $104.64 %28.90
1   $73.04  %73.36
2   (4) (3)
3   $82.95  %104.64
4   $92.45  %73.04
5   $95.09  %82.95
6   $79.20  %79.20
7   $63.66  (9)
8   $90.27  %63.66
9   $98.80  %90.27
10  $33.82  %98.80
11  (8) %33.82
12  $56.74  %56.74
13  $49.22  %49.22
14  $75.74  %75.74

out = df['A'].where( df['A']>='(' )   # 1. how to get rid of the NaN?
out

out = out.astype(dtype=str)           # 2. found that NaN is of type float, 
                                           so now all entries are str
out
```

to get:

```
2  '(4)'
11 '(8)'
```

I tried this, but that's not helping because the note value is changed to True:

```
df['A'].where( df['A']>='(' ).isna() == False

0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
```

The closest answer I [found][[Skipping char-string values while comparing to a column values of mixed type to int or float in pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208874/skipping-char-string-values-while-comparing-to-a-column-values-of-mixed-type-to]) does not help:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.A.str.strip('$'), errors='coerce')
```

performs the conversion, but transforms the '(n)' note value to nan.

To sum up: 
The problem is the mixed types in the columns, due to the notes:
I cannot just strip the '$' or '%', then convert to float.
I also need to document where these were.

I am probably blind to a simple solution...

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: @MCC, If one of the below answers helped, feel free to accept one (green tick on left). Or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment...
Can you use df.loc[] to extract ones with '('?

```
withnotes = df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('\(')]
output = [(i, row.A) for i, row in withnotes.iterrows()]
output
```

Above example parses only column A and returns a list of tuples:
    output = [(2, '(4)'), (11, '(8)')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` accessor for this:

```
res = df.loc[df['A'].str[0] == '(', 'A']
```

This results in a series:

```
2     (4)
11    (8)
Name: A, dtype: object
```

If you need a dataframe:

```
res = df.loc[df['A'].str[0] == '(', 'A'].to_frame()
```